# Dual touch screens won’t do 'touch' at the same time

Tags: windows, display, touchscreen, usb-c, touch

My primary monitor is 24” non-touch screen, let’s call it Alpha.
I have two identical external touch screens, let's call them Bravo and Charlie.

I can connect each touch screen individually with full touch support.
That is, when I connect Bravo with two cables (GPU’s HDMI to Bravo HDMI and PC’s UDB-C to Bravo USB-C), the Windows desktop is shown on Bravo, and Bravo acts as a touch screen. Initially it acts as a touch pad for the primary monitor, but using the ‘Tablet PC Settings’ Setup button (the white screens), Bravo is configured as it’s own independant touch screen.
I can repeat this process for Charlie on it’s own, and the results are the same.

However, when I try to connect Bravo AND Charlie at the same time, both show the extended Windows desktop, but only one works as a touch screen. I can move the mouse around all screens, but the touch response only works on one screen. This occurs whether I plug everything in before starting the PC, or plug them in one by one after the PC is up and running.

Using a utility called USBDeview, I observe that upon connecting Bravo there are 4 new devices active, despite being only a single touchscreen. One of these is called ‘TouchScreen’ and has a serial number (Bravo). Plugging in Charlie, however, adds only one device to the list, and it’s not labled as ‘TouchScreen’.
When I swap Charlie for Bravo and repeat, the serial number of the TouchScreen (now Charlie) is identical to the one previously recorded as Bravo.

I may be wrong but it feels like Windows can’t differentiate between these two identical touch screen devices.

Is this possible, and could it explain my issues with running both touch screens simultaneously?

——————————————————

My gear:
2x 15.6 inch Touchscreen Portable Monitor (Brand: Bnztruk),
Dell XPS 8930, Windows 11,
GPU: GTX 1070,
Powered USB Hub: Targus 4-Port USB Powered Hub with 4A AC adapter

Touchscreen Monitor Interface: 1xmini HDMI port, 2xType-c (Power Supply or Signal input port, Touch Port), 1xType-c (OTG Port:Only connect a keyboard or mouse).

USBDeview HTML report. The first item is the last connected (Charlie). The lowest five rows are the first-connected touch screen (Bravo), including the serial number which is identical if I swap Bravo and Charlie:
[USBDeview HTML report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dXbv.jpg)

Comment: So you connect and setup the first display, what happens, you connect and attempt to configure the second display exactly, please edit your question to explicitly describe what happens. “It doesn’t work” isn’t detailed enough, we can only go off what you describe, and you wouldn’t need our help if it worked.

Comment: It is better if you edited your question to provide clarification.  As comments can get deleted

Comment: OK. I've now done that. (Sorry, I'm new here.)